# How to ensure the data consistent when there are multiple services handle 1 model?

Tags: microservices

I have 2 services named JobService and CompanyService. These services have also location table. Location table always is eventually consistent.
  But you imagine, I have a record in Location table (its data in JobService and CompanyService is the same):

```
{
    Id:5jg3,
    Address: "Dai La, VN"
} (0)
```

In JobService, I adjust it became:

```
{
    Id:5jg3,
    Address: "Thang Long, VN"
} (1)
```

At this moment, a message publish into Job-Company queue. While this message haven't received by CompanyService, I adjust it in CompanyService:

```
{
    Id:5jg3,
    Address: "Ha Noi, VN"
}(2)
```

At this moment, a message publish into Company-Job queue.
  At last, the JobService receive data (2) and change its record to (2), and concurrently the CompanyService receive data (1) and change its record to (1), **synonymous with the record of location table which has Id 5jg3 in JobService and CompanyService have different data.**
  I look through some solution, like Orchestration(SAGAS), Event store, API composition but they are far because my apps have built long time ago.
My data don't have ModifiedDate or VersionID so I cant check, I puzzle whether use this solution.
  I want services's data are consistent. What solution I have easier to handle this issue?

Comment: You need to format this. Don't use HTML tags in your question. Use the toolbar buttons at the top of the question to format your question properly.

Comment: I cant get you question clearly

Comment: Oh. I've highlight the problem I considered. The data at 2 services differ.